# Enable two input type time when checkbox is checked jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

This code is a looped checkbox and two looped input type time. I want to enable the input type time if the checkbox is checked.

```html
 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
     {!! Form::checkbox('day_check[]', $day, null, array('class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12')) !!}
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    {!! Form::time('start_time[]', null, array('class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12', 'id' => 'start')) !!}
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
   {!! Form::time('end_time[]', null, array('class' => 'form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12', 'id' => 'end')) !!}
</div>
```

```js
$('input[name^="start_time"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[name^="end_time"]').prop('disabled', true);

$('input[name^="day_check"]').each(function(index) {
    $(this).change(function(index){
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('input[name^="start_time['index']"]').each(function(){ 
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
           });
             
           $('input[name^="end_time['index']"]').each(function(){ 
             $(this).prop('disabled', false);
           });
         } else {
           $('input[name^="start_time['index']"]').each(function(){ 
             $(this).prop('disabled', true);
           });
           $('input[name^="end_time['index']"]').each(function(){
             $(this).prop('disabled', true);
           });
         }
    })
});
```

Another, how can get the value from database (json format) to form value in update using laravel from a looped input type time?

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looping using @**foreach** in your blade template.

You need to differ each **input** *name* attributes for each loop.

Comment: yes i am using @foreach in my blade template. Can I differ it using the index? I added the jquery above but it doesn't work.